# Login IP's file location

Tags: log, ip

I like to know where the log files that store the SSH logins are located, the last login IP is shown when logged in via SSH so I'm sure they are kept somewhere, can anyone shed som light on this?

System: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `last` command to view login logs:

```
last -d
```

Will, to quote the manual page:

> For non-local logins, Linux stores not only the host name of the
>                 remote host but its IP number as well.  This  option  translates
>                 the IP number back into a hostname.

There is also:

```
last -i
```

> This  option is like -d in that it displays the IP number of the
>                 remote host, but it displays the IP number  in  numbers-and-dots
>                 notation.

for more information run `man last` to view the manual page.

You can also use `lastb`, which will display only the bad login attempts:

```
sudo lastb
```

`last` reads from:

```
/var/log/wtmp
```

`lastb` reads from:

```
/var/log/btmp
```

You can also view the last successful login of a user with this:

```
lastlog -u USERNAME
```

which, if it is a ssh login, will display something like:

```
Last login: Thur Jan 02 09:52:12 2014 from 192.168.1.5
```

Comment: Perfect, all I needed.